# Multiple push URLs automatically setup

Tags: git

at present my local repository .git/config has a number of pushurls (gitea instance, directory instance)  and this works as expected.

How can a bare repository be configured to contain the multiple push urls so that fresh clones/pulls will have this setup rather than requesting users (hopefully) execute the needed command to manually add the additional push repositories

Comment: the remotes are not cloned. Try it at home: git init a new repo A and clone it locally into B. B will have A as remote. Now clone B into C. C will have B as remote but not A.

Comment: However, you may explore a git clone hook or add some script to your repo that runs multiple instances of git remote add...